# float element go to bottom when scroll bar exist

Tags: html, css

```
<div class="con">
    <div class="left" id="left">
        <input type="button" value="set the height of the left panel" id="open" />
    </div>
    <div class="right" id="right"></div>
</div>
```

The `left` and `right` panel are both floated left,they work well when no scroll bar exist,however if the height of the `left` panel changed,and the scroll bar will display,then the `right` panel will go to bottom.

See exmaple [here](http://jsfiddle.net/hgm7L/):

At first,the `right` div will display beside the `left`,when you click the button,the `right` will go to bottom.

How to fix it?

---

### update

In fact I can not set the absolute size of the left and right div,since I want them resize according the content autoly.

Fullcode:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="en-US">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title></title>
    <style type="text/css">
        html,body{
            padding:0px;
            margin:0px;
            height:100%;
        }
        .con{
            float:left;
            position:relative;
            left:100px;;
            top:100px;
            border:2px solid red;
            max-height:80%;
            overflow-y:auto;
        }
        .left{
            background-color:black;
            position:relative;
            float:left;

        }
        .right{
            background-color:blue;
            position:relative;
            float:left;
            width:300px;
            height:200px;
        }
    </style>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        window.onload=function(){
            document.getElementById("open").onclick=function(){
                document.getElementById("left").style.height="900px";
                //document.getElementById("right").style.width="300px";
                //document.getElementById("right").style.height="500px";
            }
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="con">
        <div class="left" id="left">
            <input type="button" value="set the height of the left panel" id="open" />
        </div>
        <div class="right" id="right"></div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: jSFiddle seems to have issues... can you paste your whole code in the question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works...

```
.con{
    float:left;
    position:relative;
    left:100px;;
    top:100px;
    border:2px solid red;
    max-height:80%;
    overflow-y:scroll;
}
```

Comment: Oh,yeah. It works,but I the y-scroll bar is always display in IE.

Comment: Documentation doesn't seem to differ for both, but apparently the behavior varies :)

Comment: In IE, both "overflow-y:auto" and "overflow-y:scroll" have the same behavior.

Comment: Check this link for more info: http://remysharp.com/2008/01/21/fixing-ie-overflow-problem/

Comment: You are right,I set it `overflow-y:scroll;padding-right:20px` in ie,then the scroll bar disappear if not needed,but it always display in other browser.

Answer (score 0):

The best way is to make the left and/or right panel a bit more "narrow"